# Keep order billing first and last names auto updated from user data in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, user-data

So, I have a script that uses WC API to get billing_last_name in another application. I recently added a plugin that lets a user connect to the website via social networks. This creates an account automatically with first name/ last name from the social network.

When placing an order, I want billing_first_name and billing_last_name fields to be hidden but at the same time to be autocompleted after the order from the first_name and last_name of the account created earlier (of the user placing the order).
I tried the following code but I get a 500 error on the whole site:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'custom_process_order1', 10, 1);
function custom_process_order1($order_id) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();

    update_user_meta($current_user->billing_first_name$current_user_id, "first_name");
    update_user_meta($current_user->billing_last_name, $current_user_id, "last_name");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has errors and mistakes. Try the following instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'update_order_first_and_last_names', 30, 2 );
function update_order_first_and_last_names( $order, $posted_data ) {
    $user_id = $order->get_customer_id(); // Get user ID

    if( empty($user_id) || $user_id == 0 )
        return; // exit

    $first_name = $order->get_billing_first_name(); // Get first name (checking)

    if( empty($first_name) ){
        $first_name = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_first_name', true );
        if( empty($first_name) )
            $first_name = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', true );

        $order->set_billing_first_name($first_name); // Save first name
    }

    $last_name  = $order->get_billing_last_name(); // Get last name (checking)

    if( empty($last_name) ){
        $last_name = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_last_name', true );
        if( empty($last_name) )
            $last_name = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', true );

        $order->set_billing_last_name($last_name); // Save last name
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the answer. However ,when using the code above, it gives an empty error when trying to checkout. (it shows like an error when a field was not completed during checkout but it has no text). And the checkout process does not continue to the payment part. Any ideas?

Comment: @GeorgeImbrea sorry there was 2 mistakes in my code (it was `empty()` instead of `emty()`). I have updated the code.